# Prevent Imageview custom background clipping

Tags: android, android-layout

I have turned an image view into circular shape by defining my own background for it.

**circle.xml:**

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:innerRadius="0dp"
    android:shape="ring"
    android:thicknessRatio="1.9"
    android:useLevel="false"
    >
    <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />

    <stroke
        android:width="10dp"
        android:color="@android:color/white" />
</shape>
```

**shadow_rect.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/circle"/>

</layer-list>
```

**mainActivity.xml:**

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView4"
    android:layout_width="157dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:background="@drawable/profile_image"
    android:cropToPadding="false"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/banner_iamge"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/banner_iamge"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.501"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/banner_iamge"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/banner_iamge"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.476"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/layer_4" />
```

**But the imageview circle clips like this:**

As you can see the circular white ring around the profile image is getting clipped. I want that white ring to show around the image without clipping

[image: clipped imageview]

*How can I solve this?*

Comment: what do you want to do?

Comment: @AbhinavGupta as you can see the circular white ring around the image is getting clipped. I want that white ring to show around the image without clipping

Comment: can you post full display code of Imagview?

Comment: use padding in image view android:padding = "6dp"

Comment: @mehul there you go, I've added it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this lib

```
dependencies {
implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
}
```

XMl replace Imagview with this

```
<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/profile_image"
android:layout_width="96dp"
android:layout_height="96dp"
android:src="@drawable/profile"
app:civ_border_width="2dp"
app:civ_border_color="#FF000000"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

The background is a fill of the view container, **it will not shrink the content**. So my suggestion to you is to create a custom view for what you want to achieve.

There are some great projects on GitHub. One of my favorites is this one: https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView